# Show icons corresponding to the file type in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I need to show the ICONS corresponding to file type.
For example i do have "sample.doc" in a string, which i show it in a anchor tag as link to make it downloadable. The link will have file name as shown below

```
<a title="Sample" target="_blank" href="\files\sample.doc">Sample</a>
```

What i need is i want the link to be shown like below

[image]

There are many filetypes i would require to show on the web page. How can I achieve this. A starting point will be good for me to continue with it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this (pseudo-code)

```
foreach(var file in files){
 var extension = Path.GetExtension(file)

 ...
 <a title="Sample" target="_blank" href="\files\sample.doc">
   <img src="/images/@(extension).png" />
   Sample
 </a>
}
```

Comment: In this solution you have to check if file for icon exists

Comment: @Garath I think in any solution you will have to do this one or the orther way

Comment: I just want to point out that your code is missing this check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything on client side. There are helping links:

- http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Attach_icons_to_anything_with_CSS
- http://cool-javascripts.com/jquery/add-icons-to-your-links-automatically-using-jquery-css.html
- http://baldwindavid.github.io/jquery-icon/demo/

Answer (score 0):

We can show file according to file extension in asp.net. All we need to download file icon images then write some code to check extension of file and get file icon according to that.

Following function can be used to get file Icon:

```html
private string GetIconForFile(string FileName)
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
        extension = extension.Trim('.').ToLower();
        return "~/fileicons/" + extension + ".png";
    }
```

Here is the link to full example:http://programmerskills.blogspot.in/2016/05/show-file-icons-with-filename-in-aspnet.html